# Passing a property value in Maven goal is not working. pom.xml variable does not reflect in to artifact pom.xml at maven repository

Tags: maven

I am trying to get dependency version at run time from command line in maven, but it does not reflect into artifact pom at maven repository.

My project pom is  like :-

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentProject</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0.14</version>
  </parent>

    <properties>
            <my.version>${my.version}</my.version>
    </properties>

      <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>childProject</artifactId>

      <dependencies>

                <dependency>            
                <artifactId>someArtifact_one</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.company.project</groupId> 
                <version>${my.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>            
                <artifactId>someArtifact_one</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.company.project</groupId> 
                <version>${my.version}</version>
                </dependency>          

        </dependencies>
```

My command is like - **mvn install -Dmy.version=5.6.0.12**, project is build successfully and uploaded at maven repository , but when I verify artifact pom.xml at maven repository its same as.

```
<dependency>            
    <artifactId>someArtifact_one</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId> 
    <version>${my.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I think it should be like below at maven repository.

```
<dependency>            
    <artifactId>someArtifact_one</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId> 
    <version>5.6.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

How could I resolve this issue, or if someone has some other solution for this issue please suggest.

Comment: `<my.version>${my.version}</my.version>` overwrites the value you pass in goal. check my answer for fix

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because, you are over-writing the value you pass in goal `-Dmy.version=5.6.0.12` with the properties tag in pom.xml. To fix it, Either you can remove this properties tag completely (or) set it as below

```
<properties>
        <my.version>5.6.0.12</my.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: hi Thanga thanks for answer , I already tried by removing properties tag it was not working, and what you are proposing is giving hard coded value in version tag, which i don't want because i have 10 module which have this version(same version which I pass from command line and also some module has inter dependency), and its a tedious for anyone to change a version in all 10 pom.

Comment: Removing properties tag means removing the inner tags also. I mean remove `<properties>    <my.version>${my.version}</my.version>  </properties>` completely and check.

Comment: If you have this properties in parent pom also, that too has to be removed. `com.company.project.parentProject`

Comment: I did that too Thanga !

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass the arguments as : `-Darguments="-Dparam1=val1 -Dparam2=val2" in CI environment`
As mentioned in this article : [enter link description here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/07/passing-d-arguments-along-to-release.html)